# read more button problems for news section with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-click-event

I am trying to make a page with news items, just like blog posts and I fetch the news items with php and I want to limit the number of chars for news and show read more link. When a user clicks read more it should display all the content and a hide button. When the user clicks hide it should hide the content and display the original state.
The problem I am having is when I click read more on a news item it creates hide links on other post items and also shows the content on other news.

I have posted my solution on Fiddle since there are many lines of code. If I did not provide all the code please tell because this is my 1st post on Fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/wqXPg

Answer (score 1):

In some areas of plugin you are using find() method to keep scope within the individual news module, others you are using the whole collection of a class that is in the page

Perfect example is you start with a loop at bottom to call init() and you pass each element as an argument to init() but then it doesn't get used and you bind clcik handler to every `a.readmore` in page

More of this sort of context will help. Notice the p.find()

```
 init: function(config, p){
        $.extend(this.config, config);
        this.createSubString(p);
        p.find('a.read-more').on('click', news.show);
    }
```

Also look closely at your use of `news.container`. It is every container in page with that class

Answer (score 1):

When creating a plugin, you should follow the [guidelines that the JQuery team has set up](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

It is much easier to maintain, inspect and understand code within a clear scope, such as within one clearly defined function. "Jumping" around functions and passing along parameters everywhere is messy and can lead to spaghetti code.

If you can grasp the [concept of scope](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/), and how to construct a plugin, it will be much easier.

I made [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/WLup9/) you can study and learn from.

Comment: thx, i will check these out..but I wasn't trying to make a plugin

Comment: @Mythriel That's interesting, I assumed it was a plugin because you treated it similarly to a plugin, with settings and all that jazz. In any case, you can remove the plugin part and just make it execute at document load, there's no reason to wrap your code inside an object filled with function properties if you're not making a plugin.

Comment: I am fairly new to JS, I have an background with full OOP languages and I started structuring my code that way after watching some tuts. Anyway making it as a plugin is not a bad idea. I like how you did it.

Comment: I would suggest that, instead of substringing the news text, you should let all the text be there and just set a fixed height with `overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` and then animate the container to its full size when the link is clicked. It saves memory and is easier to do since you don't have to store both substring and full text, but rather only full height and fixed height.

Comment: yes i already did that based on some feedback of a designer...because he wanted to display text for the substring and when clicked read more to display entire html